# Why is the file not being copied? (Illegal char < > at index 14: Levels\default)

Tags: java

My file is not copied, when I press Enter, it gives an error: Illegal char <

> at index 14: Levels\default

```
private static void copyFile(File source, File dest) {
        try {
            Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```
case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER -> {
    if (new File(panel.level[panel.levelPage].levelPath).exists()) {
       copyFile(new File(panel.level[panel.levelPage].levelPath), new File(panel.path + panel.levelRename));
       try {
          Files.delete(Paths.get(panel.level[panel.levelPage].levelPath));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

I don't know why, but the same code in MousePressed func works

Comment: Just a guess - I suppose `Levels\default` is the path to the file? Perhaps there is a `\n` or other whitespace character appended at the end when you press enter?

Comment: yes, i just added "e.getKeyCode!=KeyEvent.VK_ENTER" to the condition and it worked, thanks